# PHP uploaded fb user's image isn't viewable?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm working on FB login on my site and I have all done except one weird problem.
I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799072/how-to-get-a-facebook-users-profile-picture-in-php) and it works fine except that the image uploaded is empty.

What can cause the corruption of the image or how can I fix this issue? When I download uploaded image on my desktop, it just says `we can't open this file`

```
$image = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fid.'/picture?type=large');
$dir = dirname(__file__).'/avatar/'.$fid.'.jpg';
file_put_contents($dir, $image);
```

Comment: Try using curl to make the request. Since the graph url gets redirected file_get_contents function doesn't follow the redirection.

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't work. When usign curl or `https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/` it doesn't even upload the image file.

Comment: ok, this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4564420/3498491 worked for me. Thanks!